# How to set up Apache Spark to have more cores (slaves)?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to run a big dataset with Apache Spark (Java API)

I don't understand well how to set it up to have a master and some slaves. This is how I have the environment :

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("LOG-16k 32 cores-persist")
                //.config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "10000s")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/")
                .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
                .config("spark.eventLog.dir", "file:/home/XXX/temp/spark-events")
                .config("spark.history.fs.logDirectory", "file:/home/XXX/temp/spark-events")
                //.config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100000)
                .master("local[32]").getOrCreate();
```

Comment: You're running this on the local machine (no cluster) but want slaves? You should set up a cluster for that

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you'll need more then one machine to get any distrubuted processing

You should read over the Spark documentation on setting up one of the following

- Spark Standalone
- Apache YARN
- Apache Mesos
- Kubernetes

Or you can find community offered schedulers such as Hashicorp Nomad - https://learn.hashicorp.com/nomad/spark/pre

You'll also want to use a distributed filesystem such as HDFS or Ceph because if you really do have a large dataset, reading it from one disk will be your bottleneck

---

If you simply want log analysis, Apache Hive/Presto/Drill or Elasticsearch would likely be more optimal than Spark

Comment: I have my pc and an external server, but I'm having problems to use both of them. I'm asking because I really don't know, so I can not do this in the IDE? I need to do that on the terminal? And yes, it is a big dataset (2 millions variables)

Comment: Your IDE is not the limitation. What types of problems??? 2 million is not a volume. It's only a number. 2 million bytes is not even 2MB. Even 200GB of data can still process quickly on a single machine in under an hour, if properly parallelized

Comment: the dataset is 150 gb. I have been asked to use Spark on a single machine, now I need to use it in a cluster. I will check the option that you are giving me. I think my problem is to make the connection to se server, I'm not a programmer, so I tried to follow tutorials but I always failed using the terminal and the IDE

Comment: Okay, then create a new post including all the steps and errors that you took, and maybe someone can help. Note: a cluster of one is still a valid cluster... Sounds like your issue is installing and configuring a scheduler. I've seen plenty of tutorials on Spark Standalone

Comment: I run it standalone with 1 cluster (it works), I want multiple clusters, I tried tutorial for that and didn't work. I will create another post.

Comment: Why? One Spark job cannot use multiple clusters at the same time. You mean machines?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I'm a little confused with the terms. I want 1 master node with some slaves. In the next days I will put the mistakes- Thank you

Comment: And you aren't able to find *anything on that*? I posted a link and there is this as well https://medium.com/@marcovillarreal_40011/creating-a-spark-standalone-cluster-with-docker-and-docker-compose-ba9d743a157f

Comment: I said that what I find didn't work and I think is because of the server, thank you for the link.

Comment: And it's not clear what you had found or tried before. Which server?